# Jquery selecting href with *=

Tags: jquery

My website has a main image that changes depending on what thumbnails you click on. For a certain main picture, I want text specific to that image to populate. The text starts out as display:none; and then I have it revealed with .show();. Nothing seems to be happening with my code, so any help would be much appreciated. The jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.fn.exists = function() {
    return this.length > 0;
};
if ($("div.bigimage a[href*='karina']").exists()) {
    $("ul li.karina").show();
    $("ul li.natalia").hide();
    $("ul li.celeste").hide();
}
else if ($("div.bigimage a[href*='natalia']").exists()) {
    $("ul li.karina").hide();
    $("ul li.natalia").show();
    $("ul li.celeste").hide();
}
else if ($("div.bigimage a[href*='celeste']").exists()) {
    $("ul li.karina").hide();
    $("ul li.natalia").hide();
    $("ul li.celeste").show();
}
else {
    $("ul li.karina").hide();
    $("ul li.natalia").hide();
    $("ul li.celeste").hide();
}
```

});​

the html it is trying to select is:

```
​<div class="bigimage">
<li>
<a href="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0103/5102/products/Natalia_1024x1024_IMG_5760.jpg?4679">picture here</a></li>
</div>

<ul>
<li id="model-name" class="karina">Karina is 5'7" and is wearing a size 34 C/D Regular</li>
            <li id="model-name" class="celeste">Celeste is 5'8" and is wearing a size 34 C/D Regular</li>
            <li id="model-name" class="natalia">Natalia is 5'10" and is wearing a size 34 A/B Tall</li>
</ul>​​​​​​
```

Comment: Your `if` statements will always evaluate to `false`. Try, for example, using: `($("div.bigimage a[href*='karina']").length)`

Comment: Do you have a demo we can see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a result of case sensitivity: you are looking for `natalia` but the link url contains `Natalia`.  There is also a much shorter way to write your code:

```
$("ul li").hide(); // hide all
var url = $("div.bigimage a")[0].href;
if (url.indexOf("Karina") > -1) {
    $("ul li.karina").show();
}
else if (url.indexOf("Natalia") > -1) {
    $("ul li.natalia").show();
}
else if (url.indexOf("Celeste") > -1 ) {
    $("ul li.celeste").show();
}
```

Comment: Also, keep in mind that duplicate `id`s are illegal.  Not relevant to your current problem, but potentially creating a problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A call to jquery with a selector does not return a boolean, it returns a collection of matched elements.

So, instead of testing something like :

```
if ($("div.bigimage a[href*='karina']") === true) {
...
}
```

You can test the size of the collection returned by jQuery :

```
if ($("div.bigimage a[href*='karina']").length > 0) {
...
}
```

More informations here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 0):

Add this little function to jQuery

`jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}`

And then you can test with

`if ($("div.bigimage a[href*='karina']").exists()) {...}`

Solution from here [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to use a string.match statement.

like

```
 if ( $("div.bigimage a").attr('href').match("karina") ) { 
//some action here
  }
```

`$("div.bigimage a").attr('href')` would return a string and .match would find it :)

It's just an idea in case you might find it easier.